# Removing html data property using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I remove the "data-simplebar" entirely by using jquery, and how to put it back. Going to use it in media breakpoints

Before

```
<div id="main-desc-text" data-simplebar="">  
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```

After

```
<div id="main-desc-text">  
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```

Comment: Please, do some research and try some things (and show that research and attempts in the question) before asking. That would have led to http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Comment: things I've done haven't been working, I'll work it out, sorry for that

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan agree. A simple googling would have led to the solution.

Comment: or if it's not working then you need to provide all relevant code

Answer (score 4):

```
<div id="main-desc-text" data-simplebar="">  
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```

To remove:

```
$('#main-desc-text').removeAttr('data-simple-bar')
```

To add:

```
$('#main-desc-text').attr('data-simple-bar', '')
```